# How to proceed with this counting problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question is —
How many functions are there from the set ${1,2,...,n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer, to the set ${{0,1}}$ that assign $1$ to exactly one of the positive integers less than $n$?

I have done this — there are $(n-1)$ elements in the domain that are less than $n$. So we have $(n-1)$ choices to which $1$ can be assigned. Once that is done, every other element in the domain is mapped to $0$. So I think the answer is just $(n-1)$.
This is wrong, it should be $2(n-1)$, but I do not understand where the $2$ is coming from.

Comment: Their interpretation sounds like $1$ is assigned to exactly one of the integers strictly less than $n$ as well as possibly or not being assigned to $n$ itself.  They count both `00010` as well as `00011` as being valid.  You counted only where $n$ mapped to zero.  There are just as many where $n$ was mapped to $1$ as well, hence the factor of two.

Comment: I agree that it is ambiguous.  "Among all integers, exactly one of them mapped to $1$ and it must be the case that the number mapping to $1$ was strictly less than $n$"  is different than "Among the integers strictly less than $n$, exactly one of those is mapped to $1$."  The phrasing is unclear which of these two was intended.

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh oh, I see it. Thank you!

Comment: The phrasing is clear enough: exactly one of the first $n-1$ functional values is 1 ($n-1$ possibilities), the value at argument $n$ can be $0$ or $1$ ($2(n-1)$ possibilities).